# Most Efficient Way of Combining or Joining Objects Read From Separate XML Files

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-serialization, xml-parsing

I have a large amount of data which is received in separated XML files each morning. I need to combine the objects within the XML and generate a report from them. I am looking to use an optimal solution for this problem.

To demonstrate I have fabricated the following example:

There are 2 XML files:

The first is a list of languages and the countries they are spoken in. The second is a list of products and the countries they are sold in. The report I generate is the product name followed by the languages the packaging has to be in.

XML1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<languages>
  <language>
    <name>English</name>
    <country>8</country>
    <country>9</country>
    <country>3</country>
    <country>11</country>
    <country>12</country>
  </language>
  <language>
    <name>French</name>
    <country>3</country>
    <country>6</country>
    <country>7</country>
    <country>13</country>
  </language>
  <language>
    <name>Spanish</name>
    <country>1</country>
    <country>2</country>
    <country>3</country>
  </language>
</languages>
```

XML2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<products>
  <product>
    <name>Screws</name>
    <country>3</country>
    <country>12</country>
    <country>29</country>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Hammers</name>
    <country>1</country>
    <country>13</country>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Ladders</name>
    <country>12</country>
    <country>39</country>
    <country>56</country>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Wrenches</name>
    <country>8</country>
    <country>13</country>
    <country>456</country>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Levels</name>
    <country>19</country>
    <country>18</country>
    <country>17</country>
  </product>
</products>
```

Sample Program Output:

```
 Screws ->  English, French, Spanish
 Wrenches ->  English, French
 Hammer - > French, Spanish
 Ladders-> English
```

Currently I deserialise into a DataSet and then use linq to join across the datasets to generate the required report strings. (Shown Below - Passing the names of the files in as command line arguments).

```
public static List<String> XMLCombine(String[] args)
{
    var output = new List<String>();
    var dataSets = new List<DataSet>();
    //Load each of the Documents specified in the args
    foreach (var s in args)
    {
        var path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + s;
        var tempDS = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            tempDS.ReadXml(path);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Custom Logging + Error Reporting
            return null;
        }
        dataSets.Add(tempDS);
    }
    //determine order of files submitted
    var productIndex = dataSets[0].DataSetName == "products" ? 0:1;
    var languageIndex = dataSets[0].DataSetName == "products" ? 1:0;
    var joined = from tProducts in dataSets[productIndex].Tables["product"].AsEnumerable()
                 join tProductCountries in dataSets[productIndex].Tables["country"].AsEnumerable() on (int)tProducts["product_id"] equals (int)tProductCountries["product_id"]
                 join tLanguageCountries in dataSets[languageIndex].Tables["country"].AsEnumerable() on (String)tProductCountries["country_text"] equals (String)tLanguageCountries["country_text"]
                 join tLanguages in dataSets[languageIndex].Tables["language"].AsEnumerable() on (int)tLanguageCountries["language_Id"] equals (int)tLanguages["language_Id"]
                  select new
                  {
                      Language = tLanguages["name"].ToString(),
                      Product = tProducts["name"].ToString()
                  };

    var listOfProducts = joined.OrderByDescending(_ => _.Product).Select(_ => _.Product).Distinct().ToList();

    foreach (var e in listOfProducts)
    {
        var e1 = e;
        var languages = joined.Where(_ => _.Product == e1).Select(_ => _.Language).Distinct().ToList();
        languages.Sort();
        //Custom simple Array to text method
        output.Add(String.Format("{0} {1}", e, ArrayToText(languages)));
    }
    return output;
}
```

This works fine but I know there must be more optimal solutions to this problem (particularly when the XML files are huge in real life). Does anyone have experience in alternate approaches (other than linq) or advice on optimising the current approach which would bring me closer to the best solution?

Many thanks in advance.

**Solution**
Implementation of suggested solutions:
Casperah's approach using Dictionaries processed data set in 312ms.
yamen's approach using Linq Lookup processed data set in 452ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems, memory usage and CPU usage.

To limit the memory usage you can use XmlReader, which only reads a small chunk of the huge xml files.
To limit CPU usage you should have an index on the country code.

I would do like this:
1. Read all languages and insert it into a dictionary like this:
    // The key is country, the value is a list of languages.
    Dictionary> countries = new Dictionary>();
2. Read products one  at a time using XmlReader
3. Lookup countries and write out Languages maybe using a HashSet to avoid duplicate Languages.

That would be my approch - Good luck

I have created this example:

```
        Dictionary<int, List<string>> countries = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();

        XmlReader xml = XmlReader.Create("file://D:/Development/Test/StackOverflowQuestion/StackOverflowQuestion/Countries.xml");
        string language = null;
        string elementName = null;
        while (xml.Read())
        {
            switch (xml.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    elementName = xml.Name;
                    break;

                case XmlNodeType.Text:
                    if (elementName == "name") language = xml.Value;
                    if (elementName == "country")
                    {
                        int country;
                        if (int.TryParse(xml.Value, out country))
                        {
                            List<string> languages;
                            if (!countries.TryGetValue(country, out languages))
                            {
                                languages = new List<string>();
                                countries.Add(country, languages);
                            }
                            languages.Add(language);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        using (StreamWriter result = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Development\Test\StackOverflowQuestion\StackOverflowQuestion\Output.txt"))
        {
            xml = XmlReader.Create("file://D:/Development/Test/StackOverflowQuestion/StackOverflowQuestion/Products.xml");
            string product = null;
            elementName = null;
            HashSet<string> languages = new HashSet<string>();
            while (xml.Read())
            {
                switch (xml.NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element:
                        elementName = xml.Name;
                        break;

                    case XmlNodeType.Text:
                        if (elementName == "name")
                        {
                            if (product != null && languages != null)
                            {
                                result.Write(product);
                                result.Write(" -> ");
                                result.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", languages.ToArray()));
                                languages.Clear();
                            }
                            product = xml.Value;
                        }
                        if (elementName == "country")
                        {
                            int country;
                            if (int.TryParse(xml.Value, out country))
                            {
                                List<string> countryLanguages;
                                if (countries.TryGetValue(country, out countryLanguages))
                                    foreach (string countryLanguage in countryLanguages) languages.Add(countryLanguage);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It produces this example:

```
Screws -> English, French, Spanish
Hammers -> Spanish, French
Ladders -> English
Wrenches -> English, French
```

XmlReader.Create takes an uri, you could also use something like: "http://www.mysite.com/countries.xml"

Comment: Thank you for your work on this. The dictionary approach was very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

OK this is still LINQ to XML, but I think it's quite efficient in so far as the algorithm goes. The only problem is if your XML is very large (ie larger than RAM can hold). Otherwise, it won't get much faster than this.

Assuming `languageFile` and `productFile` contain the relevant XML files.

Turn the languages into a lookup:

```
var languages = (from language in XElement.Load(languageFile).Descendants("language")
                from country in language.Elements("country")
                select new {Language = language.Element("name").Value, Country = country.Value})
                .ToLookup(l => l.Country, l => l.Language);
```

Then get the products with the language lookup:

```
var products = from product in XElement.Load(productFile).Descendants("product")
               select new {Product = product.Element("name").Value, 
                           Languages = product.Elements("country").SelectMany(e => languages[e.Value]).Distinct().ToList()};
```

Of course you can print them out also:

```
foreach (var product in products.Where(x => x.Languages.Count > 0))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", product.Product, String.Join(", ", product.Languages));
}
```

Which returns:

```
Screws -> English, French, Spanish
Hammers -> Spanish, French
Ladders -> English
Wrenches -> English, French
```

Comment: Thank you. Your approach is very elegant and a huge improvement over my initial attempt.

Answer (score 1):

In your case I would store the data from languages files into a dictionary or something similar, after that I would parse each product file and generate the final combined results on the fly. I suppose that this method will be faster and you would avoid memory problems which will appear for large amount of data.